# How to view Web Socket request in the chrome dev tool in Blazor Server project

Tags: websocket, blazor-server-side

We know that in **Blazor Server** project in .NET 6, everything is processed in the server and through **web socket** request the response is updated to the UI. Now as a Blazor Server developer, I wanted to see the web socket request in the browser dev tool. I tried to see the web socket request in the Chrome Dev Tool, but I don't see anything.

Can anyone help me to know why we can't see the request in the Chrome Dev tool and how to configure to see the request.

Answer (score 0):

- **Open Chrome DevTools:** First, open the `developer tools` in your `Chrome browser`. You can do this by right-clicking on your page and selecting `Inspect` or pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I`.
- **Navigate to Network Tab:** In the `DevTools` go to the `Network` tab.
- **Filter for WebSocket Connections:** To filter out WebSocket connections, you can type `ws (WebSockets)` in the filter box.
- **Find the Blazor Server WebSocket Request:** Look for a request in the Network tab that corresponds to your Blazor Server's WebSocket connection.